# Авторизация в Zimbra через MySQL

Tags: mysql, zimbra, zimlet

Всем привет!

Ситуевина такая: есть несколько рабочих сервисов с базой юзверей mysql. Требуется выполнить авторизацию/аутентификацию пользователя из базы. Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Имеются в виду аккаунты MySQL, или там просто БД с пользователями?

Comment: @Akina имеется в виду там бд с пользователями.

Первая мысль - Писать какой-то плагин/расширение которое будет обращаться к моему веб-сервису с MySQL. Верно ли это решение или есть какое-то более стандартизированное решение?

Comment: Есть некая неопределённая БД неопределённой структуры, где некие программные комплексы интерпретируют её данные как учётные записи... не, Вы правда в таких условиях рассчитываете на какое-то стандартное решение?